# Which hive version is compatible with the last spark version (2.4.3)?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Which hive version is compatible with the last spark version (2.4.3)? I didn't find this information anywhere. Currently, I always get a mismatch version error!

Comment: Are you looking for hive metastore jar compatibility with spark or hive on spark compatibility?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the information here [Hive Spark Compatibility Chart](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started#HiveonSpark:GettingStarted-VersionCompatibility)

[image]

What versions are you using? There is no official documentation for Spark 2.4.

Comment: Thanks for your response , i am using spark 2.4.3 , this is the link of the documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/index.html